# Mat-image width fill

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I was working on making cards using angular materials but for some reason, I can't get the image to fill up the space as shown in the image with red area is where I want the image to take up space.

[image]

Html:

```
 <mat-card (click)="optionPicked()">

                      <img  mat-card-image [src]="backgroundImage">

                      <mat-card-subtitle>
                        <b>{{SubtitleHere}}</b>
                      </mat-card-subtitle>

                      <mat-card-content>

                      </mat-card-content>
 </mat-card>
```

CSS3:

```
.mat-card-image {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 -16px 16px -16px;
  padding: 0%;
}
```

Comment: Your code should work without the CSS, just `<img  mat-card-image [src]="backgroundImage">`

Comment: Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example? It looks like `.mat-card-image` class is ok, but `mat-card` component has `padding`

Comment: I tried using the stackblitz example and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```css
 .card {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    background: red;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#image-container {
    background: #DDD;
}

.card-row {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-row" id="image-container">
    <img src="https://i0.wp.com/mathblog.wpengine.com/wp    content/uploads/2017/03/image005.gif?zoom=1.25&resize=429%2C262&ssl=1" class="img">
  </div>
  <div class="card-row">
    <p>Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-row">
    <p>Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-row">
    <p>Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```